# Get multiple entities without a corresponding member

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible with Hibernate to get multiple entities with a single query like

```
SELECT main.*, second.*, third.*
FROM main
LEFT JOIN second ON second.mainId = main.id
LEFT JOIN third ON third.mainId = main.id
```

Here, `second.mainId` and `third.mainId` are foreign keys and there are corresponding members in the classes. There's no member in main corresponding to the other tables.

If there was an `INNER JOIN` and just a single table, I could reverse the query, fetch the other entity and get `main` from it. This way I have no clue. I'd prefer a `Criteria` solution, but I'm interested in others, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OneToOne and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with Criteria Query will give desired result in single sql

//main Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="main")
    public class Main implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="main_id")
        int mainId;

        private String mainString;


        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
        Secound second;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
        Third Third;
...Getter-setters
}
}
```

//Secound & Third similar`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="secound")
public class Secound implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name="main_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="main"))
    private int secId;

    public String getSecoundString() {
        return secoundString;
    }

    public void setSecoundString(String secoundString) {
        this.secoundString = secoundString;
    }

    private String secoundString;
    public int getSecId() {
        return secId;
    }

    public void setSecId(int secId) {
        this.secId = secId;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="sec_id")
    private Main main;

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }



}`
```

//inside main method

```
List<Main> list=session.createCriteria(Main.class).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

**## Yes,**

**Firstly you have to create mappings according to the requirement**.

> **If you need to different classes for different tables** you can create multiple mapping files and link them using `one-to-one` or
>   `many-to-one` associations. According to the example you may have
>   classes such `main`, `second` and `third`. Refer these documentations
>   [`many-to-one`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) and [`one-to-one`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone).

-

> **If you need just one mapping file** according to your requirement you can create one mapping file and link expected properties using
>   `property` of mapping. You can associate `joins`, `sub queries`,
>   `formulas` with hibernate properties. You can refer the
>   [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-properties) of hibernate property mapping further information. You can use
>   [`named-query`](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/) and [`native sql query`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) also.

**So, refer those methods and select what is you actually wants.**